# Self assign properties in an object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to initialize an object and and assign a property of its own to one of the properties.
But my syntax is incorrect.i am referring to the following line:

```
PCMACUrl =  genericURL + "/test"
```

i have tried

```
testList[0] = {
    executionTimeSec:60,
    genericURL:"www.gmail.com",
    comments: "",
    PCMACUrl = genericURL   + "/test"
};
```

Comment: @Amberlamps you probably mean `:`

Comment: @Amberlamps The question is about a reference to self in a declaration of an object, not about a typo (ie. `=` -> `:`)

Comment: @aduch I voted to close. Seems to me they have typed the syntax correctly aside from that last line, so they should know how to create object properties. Either way, it's a pointless question of use to no-one.

Comment: @RGraham Fair enough

Comment: i did it :   PCMACUrl: genericURL   + "/test". but i get an error in chrome console :  genericURL is not defined. i just don't know javascript syntax.

Comment: Asked and answered dozens of times. Basic answer is you can't do this.

Comment: You can do it - using arrays/objects as variables (and manipulate those) or - if you like to walk on the edges - use the "evil" eval function :)

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading all together I believe this is what you are looking for:
(added after init, yes, I know, but it's clean and simple :)

```
var data = {
        'PropA': 1,
        'PropB': 2,
        'PropC': 3
    };
    data.PropD = data.PropC+5;
    console.log(data); //Object {PropA: 1, PropB: 2, PropC: 3, PropD: 8}
```

Or, another way to look at it:

- if it is possible use backend to generate the object you would like
- probably you could also just get rid of same data in same object and use it differently when you call it (referencing to first object propertie and adding second on-the-go:
  .../ `= data.PropC+anotherData.PropA` /...

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question at all. Could you please provide a code snippet that actually instantiates an object?